# Cocoapods - HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)

Tags: cocoapods, http2

I'm using Cocoapods for my dependency manager. It never had issues when trying to execute the `pod install` and `pod repo add` commands for our private 3rd party library before I updated my macOS to Ventura.
After I updated my macOS to Ventura, I got errors about HTTP/2 when trying the commands above.

When `pod repo add` , the error is

> unable to access {our vendor repo url} HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed
> cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)

When `pod install`, the error is

> Response: Stream error in the HTTP/2 framing layer

I think there is an issue in my cUrl library when connecting with the server with HTTP/2 protocol.
I've searched about it and everyone tried to set an option for cUrl lib to use HTTP/1.1 before the cUrl command is executed.

Does anyone know how to do it for Cocoapods?
Or anybody had this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue. I've multiple machine credentials in my .netrc file. The cUrl only read my first machine in the first line. So I need to rearrange the machine's credentials for the source I want to use in my Podfile.
The next question is why the cUrl only read the first machine in my .netrc file? The cUrl's guideline said that cUrl could read multiple machines in a .netrc file.